# Check for performance of a Table at the time of design

Tags: database, database-design

While designing a Table in database, how will you determine its performance? At the time of creating itself how can we ensure that performance of it is going to be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using a SQL database.

Basically you don't know the performance in the design phase. You need lots of data in the tables to be able to measure performance. But there are a couple of things to think about to help making sure the performance is as good as possible.

1. How many rows do you expect in the table? If it's only a couple of hundred rows you don't need to overthink it. But if you expect hundreds of millions of rows you need to think a lot more about performance, indexes are a big part of it.
2. Is the table read or write heavy? If you only write to it you don't want indexes since they cause slower writes. But if it's read heavy you need indexes.
3. How do you join to other tables? You want indexes on foreign keys. But in addition to that you need to make sure the other tables have the correct indexes.
4. Indexes on keys. Normally you want indexes on all primary and foreign keys.
5. Indexes on other columns. If you only write to the table and get data based on primary and/or foreign keys you shouldn't add other indexes. But if you want to search in the data you need to add indexes for those columns. And if you want to search with multiple values at the same time you might want to add composite indexes.
6. Minimize amount of indexes. But you don't want to add to many indexes for two reasons. First, each index lowers the performance on write. Second, and normally more problematic, is that the data in the indexes should be available in RAM to maximize performance. With loads of indexes on big tables you might run out of RAM, and the database needs to read indexes from disk, a big performance issue.
7. Minimize data in indexes of strings. You might be able to index only a substring, to minimize the size of the index. But you need to make sure the substring you index is pretty unique, otherwise you will get lots of hits. Or you might want to add another column with a hashcode of the string, and index that. But then you can only use the index for the full string, and you need to worry about upper and lower case as well.
8. Query. Your queries should use indexes wherever possible. But in some cases it's better to not use it. Examples could be reports that are done once per month, and they aren't time critical. Adding extra indexes for those reports could cause mentioned above.
9. Database. Different databases behave differently. Most of what is mentioned above is more or less generic, but there are database specific things that needs to be considered.
10. Testing and understanding the execution of queries. When you test your queries you need to have lots of data in the database. Do you expect there to be 10 million rows of data in the table? Test it with 50 million rows. And understand how the queries are executed, again with loads of data in the database.

As you can see there are lots to think about. But there are good news, most things can and should be updated when needed. As long as it's at least at third normal form it's usually possible to fix issues.